# What is causing the warning "invalid use of structure with flexible array member" in C?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, warnings, flexible-array-member

Okay so I've read every post about this but still don't get where's the issue. I'm coding in C.

I have this struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int num;
    char * palo[];
}tCarta;
```

When I try to compile, I get this warning for every function:

```
warning: invalid use of structure with flexible array member [-Wpedantic]
void llenarMazo(tCarta mazo[]);
```

Why is that? How can I fix it?

I'll leave a function and my main in case it helps:

```
void llenarMazo(tCarta mazo[]){
    int i;
    char * palos[] = {"Treboles", "Picas", "Diamantes", "Corazones"};
    for(i = 0; i < CANT_MAZO; i++){
       mazo[i].num = (i % CANT_FIGURAS) + 1;
       mazo[i].palo = palos[i % CANT_PALOS];
    }
    return;
}


int
main(void){
    tCarta mazo[CANT_MAZO];
    llenarMazo(mazo);
    //[...]
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what `char * palo[];` means?

Comment: You can't make an array of structures with FAM.

Comment: You did not specify the size of the included array. How would the compiler be able to create an array of such a struct without knowing the size?

Comment: @user253751 yeah, pointer to array of chars, but apparently don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: No, it's an array of pointers to char.

Comment: A pointer to an array of chars would be `char *palo`

Comment: @Gerhardh but isn't that the point of using a pointer here? That it can point to arrays of different sizes?

Comment: `char *palo[];` is an array of pointers, but the number of pointers is unspecified.

Comment: What you want is just `char *palo;`, not an array.

Comment: No, how would you do pointer arithmetics here? Where is `mazo[1]` located in memory? You can only use pointers to single objects of such a type. Not consecutive objects.

Comment: Also this is wrong:  `mazo[i].palo = palos[i % CANT_PALOS];` `palo` is an array of pointers. You cannot assign anything to an array.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, that worked.